# How to synchronize the Arraylist to the Retrofit result

Tags: java, arraylist, retrofit2, synchronizedcollection, android, gson

This is one of the APIs that working with Retrofit library.

```
 @GET("users/self/media/recent/")
        Call<List<Media>> getRecentPostList(@Query("access_token") String access_token);
```

I'm using GsonConverterFactory to output the result, and this will return a List<> object, but can I synchronize the List?

What I'm trying is to use **Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())**, and pass the result list of Gson as a parameter to the constructor of the ArrayList.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Just curious, if I'm getting you right: you're going to return a synchronized list as a result of deserialization -- why do you need this? (Synchronized data structures have extra cost, and I'd think that you'd need to make it synchronized in place).

Comment: yes, because then I am going to start lots of threads for doing lots of asynchronous network tasks with changing the list, if the list is not synchronized the data will go inconsistent.

Comment: Yep, it may be inconsistent. I was just curious wouldn't it be better to make lists synchronized right before use, and not as a deserialization result?

Comment: Umm..What did you mean? Now I'm using Collections.synchronizedList() method with the deserialized List from Retrofit, isn't it synchronized before use?

Comment: Yeah, it is. I just think that it is fine as you have it now.